# One to one EF, where one of the objects has a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have

```
public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public int AccountId { get; private set; }

    public virtual ExpenseCategory ExpenseCategory { get; private set; }

    public Expense(... params ...)
    {
        this.ExpenseCategory = new ExpenseCategory();
    }

    protected Expense()
    {
    }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual List<Expense> Expenses { get; private set; }

    ...
}

public class ExpenseCategory
{
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual BaseCategory Category { get; private set; }

    public Guid? CategoryId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Expense Expense { get; private set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Expense")]
    public int ExpenseId { get; private set; }

    // EF is a 'friend' assembly, don't worry about the internal
    internal ExpenseCategory()
    {
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // This deletes the Expense entity when it is removed from the Account
    modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>()
        .HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.AccountId })
        .Property(t => t.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    // PROBLEM STARTS HERE MAYBE
    modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
            .HasKey(e => e.ExpenseId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.ExpenseCategory)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(tc => tc.Expense);
}
```

My relation between Expense and Account is fine - it works exactly as I need it. I am now trying to introduce a 1:1 (I know MSSQL does not support it natively, but EF works around this) relation between the Expense and a Category. I want ExpenseCategory to be my mapping between an Expense and a Category. There must be only one ExpenseCategory per Expense and I want the Key of that mapping to be the ID of the Expense.

I am having trouble, with anything I try. With the current setup I am getting:

> the number of properties in the dependent and principal roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical.

I think the issue might be coming from the composite key on the Expense.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Added the following on my `ExpenseCategory`

```
public int AccountId { get; private set; }
```

And the following Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseCategory>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.ExpenseId, e.AccountId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.ExpenseCategory)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(tc => tc.Expense)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```